# Android Recycler View Adapter with TimePicker

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, timepicker

I have a Fragment with a RecyclerView where the user can introduce one or more time zones, choosing starting and ending time.

[image]

When the user taps on every hour, appears the time picker:

[image]

When the hour is selected, I want to change the text hour to the one selected by the user. I show the timePicker from the RecyclerView adapter but I don't know how to pass from onTimeSet to modify the textView of the hour. As far as I know it has to be inside RecyclerView adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. All of this happen inside RecyclerView Adapter. I added an onClick listener to the textView. Then I pass the view when I create the Dialog Fragment.

Inside the onBindViewHolder:

```
horarioViewHolder.mFromTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment(v);
                newFragment.show(((ChefAltaUnoActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");

            }
        });
```

Inside TimePickerFragment:

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


    private View mView;

    public  TimePickerFragment(View view) {
        mView = view;
    }



    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker


        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


        TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.CustomTimePickerDialogTheme, this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));


        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return timePicker;
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {


        ((TextView) mView).setText("format the time text as you want.");

    }

}
```

Hope it helps someone else.